# URL formats not supported

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, image-resizing

I am trying to resize a Bitmap using the below code, I am receiving an error on the 2nd line:

```
Image src = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Microsite\TestASP\Images\logo.png");

Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(600,600); //error occurs on this line

using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gr.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300));
}
```

The error I get is

> url formats not supported

Comment: Is the error you are getting a compilation error, or an exception?
In both cases, could you please provide more details about the error?

Comment: its a runtime error. what value needs to be passed in the bitmap constructor for width and height?

Comment: I don't see a URL anywhere on line 2. Only in line 1. Are you certain the image exists and that this is the correct path you are using?

Comment: Is the D drive mapped to a network share?

Comment: @Oded: isn't it the Visual Studio debugger that highlights the next line from where the exception was raised?

Comment: @Default - Not in my experience. It will highlight the line that caused the exception.

Comment: When I change the URL to a valid image on my computer, your code compiles and runs fine!

Comment: there's nothing to do with the path i guess. the bit map constructor is where the exception arise

Comment: Worked for me, pasted above code into a unit test and ran Green.  Can you supply the entire exception message and stack trace

Comment: @BharathNadadur - Please avoid "text speak" when you post. It makes it difficult to understand and is not considered very professional. The word is "right", not "ryt".

Comment: we are here for the solution not for chat/finding grammatical mistakes. btw,@Robert Slaney did u test with the same pixel value i have posted for width and height?

Comment: yes, copied the code directly... can you post the stack trace, not just the error message

Comment: @Oded: I think you're right. However I know I've seen that behavior somewhere, I just cannot replicate it in VS right now. No matter what, the error seems related to line 1 and not 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your D drive is mapped to somewhere other than the local machine.

Try this instead of your first line (I know it's not very pretty, it's testing a hunch):

```
Image src = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(@"D:\Microsite\TestASP\Images\logo.png")));
```