# Download PDF File

Tags: c#, path, httpwebrequest, filestream

How to give a path without hard coded?

```
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://lms.nsbm.lk/file.php/45/MIS_Notes/filename.pdf");

        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(MoodleSessioncookie);
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(MoodleSessiontestcookie);
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(moodidcookie);

        HttpWebResponse form = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseReader = form.GetResponseStream();

        FileStream fs = File.Create("HardCoded Pdf File Name");
        byte[] data = new byte[512];
        int redcount = responseReader.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        while (redcount > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(data, 0, redcount);
            redcount = responseReader.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        fs.Close();
        responseReader.Close();
```

Comment: put it in function and pass the file name as parameter.

Comment: I added Like This FileStream fs = File.Create("2._Enterprise_applications_-_MIS_17.pdf"); this is a file name i want to download our server -2._Enterprise_applications_-_MIS_17.pdf

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: how to add a Linklabel Dynamically in windows Form application

Comment: no erros when  i pass the in  file create (Hardcoded filename.pdf)it will be error Url format not support

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618027/url-formats-not-supported

Comment: but when i pass path inside file create http://lms.nsbm.lk/file.php/45/MIS_Notes Like this it will error 404 not found.how to handle like this of if web link like how to get the filename with out file hardcoded